# How do I start running a JavaFX program in NetBeans using a Java Swing application?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, javafx

I am new at Java but making progress.
I have created a JavaFX application that runs great when I "Run File" alone. However, if I drag it to the same project (and source package) in Netbeans as an existing Java app I can not get it to launch.

Netbeans is 7.2.1

The JavaFX app has a class `AdvMedia`
in main of the JavaFx app I have `launch(args)`
I have added `System.out` code to show it goes through `start` and `init` OK

In the Java program I am using the following code attached to a button event

```
AdvMedia am = new AdvMedia();
```

Any idea what I am missing?

Comment: what do you mean by `I can not get it to launch`? Any errors?

Comment: In standalone mode the JavaFx App opens a screen playing video. I do not get any screen when I make the call to the JavaFX app from the button event.

Comment: Take a look at [JavaFX for Swing developers](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/swing/jfxpub-swing.htm) - I believe you should not directly invoke `AdvMedia am = new AdvMedia();` but instead need to wrap your JavaFX UI in a [JFXPanel](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/embed/swing/JFXPanel.html) to allow it to be embedded in Swing (also ensure that the path to the javafx runtime library `jfxrt.jar` is on your hybrid Swing/JavaFX apps compile and execution library path).